# Toggle Mapbox check box while toggling HTML Table check box

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have been following https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/filter-markers/ this example to filter markers when clicked on the names. Map box uses the layer ID for filtration. It works perfectly for me, but is there a way I can link them to my table check boxes. For example, is there a way to toggle their  checkbox when my checkbox is checked.

```
<tbody class="data">
  <tr >
    <td> <input type="checkbox" id="marker1" class="marker1"> </td>// toggle the first check box in mapbox
    <td> <input type="checkbox" id="marker2" class="marker2"> </td>// toggle the second check box in mapbox
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Hi. Did you figure this out? I am working out a similar problem.